# Why is the relative path not finding the swf

Tags: html, flash, url, embed

I have this [url](http://dev.posnation.com/) and in the middle I have this embed link

```
<embed base="http://dev.posnation.com/images/" height="345" align="middle" width="743" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" salign="" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" 
allowfullscreen="false" menu="true" name="banner" bgcolor="#ffffff" devicefont="false" 
wmode="window" scale="showall" loop="true" play="true" 
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" quality="high" src="banner.swf">
```

But for some reason the flash doesnt pull up. I have the banner.swf in the /images folder as you can see with this [link](http://dev.posnation.com/images/banner.swf) what am i missing

Comment: Are you sure that .swf is not found? To me it seems that .swf is found but swf can't find the images.

Comment: yes but they might be true but i have a data.xml that has the locations of the files and they in the proper locations....click on the link in my question that has the swf with the images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I know what the problem is.

You've specified **base="http://dev.posnation.com/images/"** and **src="banner.swf"**, and you think that banner.swf will be searched in the images folder. I think it does not work that way.

Movie will still be searched in http://dev.posnation.com/. All the graphics for the movie will be searched in location specified by the *base*, while banner.swf will be searched in the location specified by *src*.

[Source](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html)

Answer (score 1):

woops ignore my previous answer. i see the problem. I used chrome's developer tools and your website throws an error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

to expand on awerti's suggestion this is how i embed from a different folder

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0" width="240" height="138" id="flashdemo" align="middle" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
<param name="movie" value="/content/flashdemo.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="wmode" VALUE="transparent">
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
<param name="base" VALUE="/content/">
<embed src="/content/flashdemo.swf" base="/content/" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" wmode="transparent" width="240" height="138" name="flashdemo" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
```